# AWS Simple Email Service - Need code to use boto3 with IAM Profile

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses, boto3

I want to access Amazon’s **SES**(Simple Email Service) using the **boto3** library and a user profile. The code I want to execute is listed below which does not work. It gives me an ***error “botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials”***, I am currently able to access **S3** services with no issue so I know my profile is setup correctly, but I cannot find code to access the SES service using a profile. I need some pointers how to get the code to work.

**SES code that *NOT* work**

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
client = boto3.client('ses','us-east-1')
response = client.list_verified_email_addresses()
```

**S3 code which currently works with a profile**

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Reference: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html

Comment: Is there a ~/.aws/credentials` file on your machine? How can you have a profile and an IAM role?

Comment: Yes there is a credentials file for my profile where I specify the access and secret keys, I will modify my quest to reflect, that I am specifying a profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your SES code, you are not using the session that you created with your profile. But in S3 code, you use the session. When you call `boto3.client()`, it knows nothing about your profile. Try this:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
client = session.client('ses','us-east-1')
response = client.list_verified_email_addresses()
```